# Use NSDateComponents to Calculate date of next month /nth week ordinal / nth weekday from today

Tags: nsdatecomponents

I am trying to calculate a date from today's date. The date that I want is next month , nth week ordinal and  nth weekday from today. I am using the code below to do it. The results of code below is wrong. If suppose today is 03/28/2013 and I am looking for date of 3rd Saturday of next Month then..I am expecting to see 04/20/2013. Instead I see 04/23/2013. I am unable to debug the issue. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks for help.

```
NSDate *todayDate = [[NSDate alloc] init]

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit |   NSMonthCalendarUnit |NSDayCalendarUnit| NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit ) fromDate:todayDate];

NSUInteger todayWeekdayValue = [dateComponents weekday];   
NSUInteger todayWeekdayOrdinal = [dateComponents weekdayOrdinal];

// recurringWeekday  / recurringMonthDay get passed on  from calling function 

NSUInteger nextWeekdayValue = [self getWeekdayValueForWeekdayName:recurringWeekday];
NSUInteger nextWeekdayOrdinal = recurringMonthDay;

[dateComponentsToAdd setMonth:1];
[dateComponentsToAdd setWeekday:nextWeekdayValue - todayWeekdayValue];
[dateComponentsToAdd setWeekdayOrdinal:nextWeekdayOrdinal - todayWeekdayOrdinal];

 NSDate *nextDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponentsToAdd toDate:todayDate options:0];
```